# Progress bar error in Firefox but works fine in IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
   Here is the code iam using for Progress bar of jQuery UI 
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divprogressbar").progressbar({
        value: 1 
    });
    $("#divprogressbar").find( ".ui-progressbar-value" ).css({"background": '#005A84'});
    $(".progress-label").text($("#divprogressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
 });

     I am using the jQuery references

    <link href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    Here is the div

    <div id="divprogressbar" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">
         <div class="progress-label" style="color: Black; padding-top: 5px;">
         </div>
    </div>
```

I have no problem in IE and chrome browsers but when i run in Firefox i am facing the following error

```
    ** $(...).progressbar is not a function **
```

Please help me i am unable to forward my application. Thanks in advance

Comment: when i run firsttime i have no erros. but after that when refresh and run then it is giving error

Answer (score 0):

you can try,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#divprogressbar").progressbar({
        value: 1 
    });
    $("#divprogressbar").find( ".ui-progressbar-value" ).css({"background": '#005A84'});
    $(".progress-label").text($("#divprogressbar").progressbar("value") + "%");
});
});
```

Comment: when i run firsttime i have no erros. but after that when refresh and run then it is giving error

Answer (score 0):

check the order in which you import your js.

It works here:

http://jsbin.com/utemu

Keeps adding things to that in the direction of yours until it breaks, or keep removing things from yours in the direction of that until it works.

Comment: when i run firsttime i have no erros. but after that when refresh and run then it is giving error